# 1-Way Within Subject ANOVA - sig value

Tags: anova, variance, spss, descriptive-statistics, manova

[image]

There is 1 independent var (AT) with two levels (PQ_Low and PQ_High).

1. My SPSS output reveals sig as 0.000
   Can I assume that my p-value is significant as it is less than the alpha level of 0.05?
2. Should I be concerned about violation of Mauchly's Test of Sphericity in this case, as there are only 2 levels?